# Modal RCP Dialog not modal

Tags: dialog, modal-dialog, rcp, e4

I'm having some trouble creating a modal Dialog in the e4 workbench.
There is a predefined dialog(org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.impl.DialogImpl), 
but the problem is that I can't figure out how to make it modal.

Maybe you guys have some clue.

Comment: You are probably better off sticking with the traditional JFace `Dialog`. There is very little documentation on the MDialog code and I have never found anything that uses it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the style for the dialog by using 'styleOverride' in the Persisted State for the dialog. The value of 'styleOverride' is the numeric value of the SWT flags you want to use.

For a application model dialog the style would normally be

```
SWT.TITLE | SWT.RESIZE | SWT.MAX | SWT.CLOSE | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL
```

which has a numeric value of `66672` so you would set this in the persisted state data:

[image]

It may be easier to stick with the traditional JFace `Dialog` as the application model `MDialog` does not give you any support for buttons etc.

Comment: I think I'll give that one a try. I'd like to have the support of Parts in my dialog!